# Low-Voltage Differential Signalling (LVDS) not working

Tags: arduino, serial, esp32, differential, lvds

I have updated the schematic and hopefully included all the suggestions.
The problem of the LED strip flickering is still there, however, I have noticed a slight improvement after altering the circuit as suggested.

[image]

Comment: Help in what way? I can see multiple issues, but without knowing what even the basic purpose or function is, or is supposed to be, I can't begin to guess.

Comment: The purpose is to extend the distance from the MCU to the LED strip.

Comment: @Nugget How, as these chips are on same schematic so they are on same PCB. So they can't extend anything. Unless they are on different boards and don't really are powered from same supply amd don't share a ground reference.

Comment: What is U4 & U5?  Are they active components, or connectors?

Comment: Why are you using LVDS for this interface?  It can't be for speed if you're just blinking LEDs.  If you really think you need a diff interface, consider RS-485.

Comment: @SteveSh, U4 & U5 are the RJ45 connectors.
The LVDS is just to extend the cable length.

Comment: I think you have 1) a voltage drop issue because of the long wire runs or 2)  you're exceeding the common mode voltage range of the LVDS receiver.

Comment: When you extend the Cat5 cable to 300 ft, are you also lengthening the ground and 5 V wires to the LED strip?

Comment: The LED strips are fairly tolerant of poor power sources. U3 will not be. Have you measured the power rails at U3?

Comment: The LED strip is powered from its own (local) power supply + a ground link back to the MCU.

Comment: U3 is 30 ft away? You need to describe your setup better. More diagrams. When people waste their energy understanding your problem, they don't have any left to solve it.

Comment: @Mattman944, U2 and U3 are getting a good 3.3V

Comment: @Mattman944, on the breadboard U2 and U3 are next to each other (as in the schematic). This is a test to see if it is possible to extend the length of the LED data line via a CAT5 cable.

Comment: Which decoupling capacitors are used for U2 and U3 and where are they placed?

Comment: You need to show the board layout too, but frankly troubleshooting this circuit doesn't make a lot of sense.  I've seen people drive ws2812 with an arduino GPIO through 10+ meters of speaker cable with no additional electronics.  The bandwidth is so low and the electronics so tolerant of distortion using LVDS is pointless.  With a basic line driver and a terminating resistor you should be able to drive a 100m easily enough.

Comment: @user1850479 That sounds interesting and I would like to try it. Everyone I have spoken to about getting an LED strip to work 100m from the MCU has said it can only be done using differential signalling. Please can you provide a part number for the line driver you would use and a schematic of what the setup would look like? Cheers.

Comment: A differential receiver will give you best noise immunity, but LVDS is for high speed (100s of Mbit/s), short range (inches) links, which is the opposite of what you want.  You could use RS-485 transmitters/receivers to send your single ended signal differentially through twisted pair, but if it were me I'd get a spool of RG59 cable, run it single ended, drive it with a CMOS line driver and a ~50 ohm series termination.  That way you don't need a receiver at the far end, just coax straight to the first LED pixel.

Comment: @user1850479, Awesome, I tried the RS-485 route and it worked a charm. Flicker-free LEDs over 100M of UTP. I am also going to test with a CMOS driver but I haven't got one in stock, so I have ordered one. Thanks for all your help - you're a legend.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because there are multiple important pins left unconnected that must not be left unconnected.

Such as the enable pins of the LVDS ICs.

Also you say the LVDS chips use different power supplies and that schematics do not resemble the fact that the chips use same supplies.

That may be the problem, because LVDS, like any other similar differential electrical communication standard such as RS-485, does not work with two data wires alone. The LVDS transceivers require a common ground reference between them.

And the RGB LED likely can't drive a 50 ohm load so the LVDS transmitter may already transmit out garbage, remove the 50 ohm resistor.

The LVDS chips are also on a breadboard and don't have bypass caps on their power supply pins. Put some 100nF bypass caps there.

Also all other unused floating logic inputs on LVDS IC must be connected to GND or VCC.

Comment: Thank you.
I have now connected pin G on each of the LVDS ICs to the 3.3V rail and G- to the ground, but I am still having the same problems.

Comment: @Nugget We don't know what problems you are having then. What do you expect to happen and what happens instead. "Doesn't work" tells nothing.

Comment: The LED signal from the MCU should stay "clean", so when it gets to the LED strip (30-300Ft. away) the LEDs light correctly. Instead, when the CAT5 length is > 1-3Ft. the signal becomes degraded.

Comment: @Nugget But in the schematics the comnectors are on same board so I don't see how this extends anything.

Comment: the schematic is just a test rig setup on a breadboard to test the ability to extend the LED data cable. I have put the LVDS receiver on its own power supply but the problem is the same.

Comment: @Justme - They may not be on the same board.  That may just be how OP drew his schematic.  I know, it's not standard or good practice, but still...

Comment: @Nugget See, that's the problem, the schematics don't resemble what you have in real life. Your schematics show you use **the same** power supply so LVDS chips **share the same ground reference**. This does not work if **the LVDS chips use different power supplies and do not share the same ground reference**. So your schematics were good but what you made does not work because it does not match the schematics.

Comment: @Justme, originally, on the breadboard everything ran from the same power supply (exactly like the schematic). Since then, I have tried different configurations as suggested by various comments. None of the suggestions so far have helped to fix the issue. The LED signal is not getting to the receiver cleanly after the CAT5 cable exceeds approx. 15Ft.

Comment: @Nugget you write "The LED signal is not getting to the receiver cleanly after the CAT5 cable exceeds approx. 15Ft.". You you have evidence for this, like a scope trace, or are you just observing that it's not working the way you want it to ?

Comment: @brhans, just that the LED strip begins to flicker when the CAT5 cable length is increased. Unfortunately, I don't own an oscilloscope.